# Android ImageView not showing in SherlockFragment

Tags: java, android, imageview, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to make an `ImageView`, in the Graphical view it shows up but when I run it on my device and the emulator the image doesn't show up. Here's my XML code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/map_mockup" />
```

and here's my Fragment1 code (I am using Fragment1 as the Fragment to display this ImageView)

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.*;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

I hope this is enough, but if you need more code of the application I'll post it.

This is the first time I'm asking a question on Stack Overflow so if I do something wrong PLEASE tell me so I can correct it, so that in the future my questions layout is correct.

Here's the code for the activity I am adding the fragment to.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

     // Declare Variable
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    String[] title;
    String[] subtitle;
    int[] icon;
    Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment3();
    Fragment fragment4 = new Fragment4();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

        // Generate title

        title = new String[] { "Main", "Nick Honegger",
                "Discounts", "About" };

        // Generate subtitle
        subtitle = new String[] { "Check nearby markets", "View your profile",
                "Coupons and deals!", "Find out more!" };

        // Generate icon
        icon = new int[] { R.drawable.action_about, R.drawable.profile_pic,
                R.drawable.collections_cloud, R.drawable.action_about };

        // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        // Pass results to MenuListAdapter Class
        mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, title, subtitle, icon);

        // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        // Capture button clicks on side menu
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
            break;
        case 3:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment4);
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

I've tried using Log.d and it shows that Fragment1 is being loaded. I'm stumped, I don't know what to do and am completely lost right here.

If it matters, the resolution for the PNG is 900x1429.

Comment: Would you be able to post the xml layout of `R.layout.drawer_main` so we can see where `R.id.content_frame` fits in?

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can think of.

First, I'm not sure if your layout code shows us the whole file or a snippet.  If it's the whole file, you're missing a closing tag on the `relativeLayout`.  If it's a snippet then ignore me.

Second, can you post the code for the Activity that you are adding this Fragment to?

Comment: It's a snippet. I forgot to include the closing tag for RelativeLayout. Thanks anyway :), and I will post it in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Please would you try this:

```
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1, "frag1");
```

instead of

```
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
```

?

If this doesn't change anything, I suggest you use Log.d to confirm that your fragment1 is actually being loaded.

Edit:

Good, then follow Arkan's line or reasoning or place a textview in your xml like this, to determine whether or not the xml is being loaded:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="if you can see me the problem must be with my image" 
    />
```

Comment: Tried it, Fragment1 is certainly being loaded, and replacing the latter with the first one didn't fix it, same results unfortunately, appreciate the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the in the onCreateView instead of the xml?That would be the first thing I'd try.Btw I used the same tutorial as you did and consider yourself lucky,mine doesnt even show the image on my device -.-